# IntelliJ IDEA: как настроить шаблон для комментариев?

Tags: java, intellij-idea

Прошу помощи.

Есть поле:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Делаю форматирование кода, используя горячие клавиши Ctrl+Alt+L, для форматирования кода.
Комментарий из однострочного превращается в многострочный:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Подскажите, пожалуйста, где либо отключить эту функцию, либо настроить шаблон, к которому среда будет приводить комментарий при Ctrl+Alt+L.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

В дополнение к ответу @RomanKonoval добавлю, что в данном разделе `JavaDoc` есть чекбокс `Do not wrap one line comments`, соответственно если его выставить, то однострочный коммент не будет разбиваться на несколько строк, после автоформатирования кода:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Благодарю за помощь! Это то, что я искал!

Answer (score 2):

`Ctrl+Alt+L` запускает форматирование кода. В IntelliJ очень много аспектов форматирования можно конфигурировать, чтобы формат соответствовал стилю кода, который вы используете. Можно отключить форматирование JavaDoc вообще, или настроить под себя в `Editor -> Code Style -> Java`:

Самый простой способ для вас - это отключить в опциях автоформатирования кода форматирование комментариев JavaDoc:

[image: опция форматирования javadoc]

Comment: Благодарю за помощь!

Answer (score 1):

Думаю никак.

`/**` - это документальный комментарий (DOC Comment) - по сути часть [спецификации JavaDoc](https://www.oracle.com/technical-resources/articles/java/javadoc-tool.html), где черным по белому написано:

> The first line contains the begin-comment delimiter ( /**).

Используйте обычный комментарий вместо Doc Comment и будет вам счастье:

```
/* test */
private String test = "test";
```

Comment: Дело в том, что в проекте принято комментировать аналогичным образом. Коллеги говорят, что в свое время где-то это настроили, но где - никто не помнит :D

Comment: @ib1855, сделайте архив настроек у кого нибудь и перенесите в свою idea ))